# systemd service won't start nodejs

Tags: systemd, services, node.js

I'm trying to get my nodejs app to start on boot. It runs fine if I start it from the command line as the user odroid.

Here is my service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=ProImage
After=network.target mysql.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/node /proimage/app.js
Restart=on-failure
RootDirectory=/proimage
WorkingDirectory=/proimage
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run:

```
sudo systemctl status proimage_daemon
```

I get:

```
odroid@odroid:~$ sudo systemctl status proimage_daemon
● proimage_daemon.service - ProImage
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/proimage_daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-02-26 09:45:30 EST; 6s ago
  Process: 30797 ExecStart=/bin/node /proimage/app.js (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
 Main PID: 30797 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)

Feb 26 09:45:29 odroid systemd[1]: proimage_daemon.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 26 09:45:29 odroid systemd[1]: proimage_daemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 26 09:45:30 odroid systemd[1]: proimage_daemon.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 26 09:45:30 odroid systemd[1]: Stopped ProImage.
Feb 26 09:45:30 odroid systemd[1]: proimage_daemon.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 26 09:45:30 odroid systemd[1]: Failed to start ProImage.
```

I've looked at journalctl using:

```
journalctl -u proimage_daemon.service
```

and it gives me the same the following:

```
odroid@odroid:~$ journalctl -u proimage_daemon.service --since 09:38
-- Logs begin at Tue 2019-02-26 09:02:47 EST, end at Tue 2019-02-26 10:02:34 EST. --
Feb 26 09:38:12 odroid systemd[1]: proimage_daemon.service: Trying to enqueue job proimage_daemon.service/stop/replace
Feb 26 09:38:12 odroid systemd[1]: proimage_daemon.service: Installed new job proimage_daemon.service/stop as 13040
Feb 26 09:38:12 odroid systemd[1]: proimage_daemon.service: Enqueued job proimage_daemon.service/stop as 13040
Feb 26 09:38:12 odroid systemd[1]: proimage_daemon.service: Job proimage_daemon.service/stop finished, result=done
Feb 26 09:38:12 odroid systemd[1]: Stopped ProImage ICU.
Feb 26 09:39:19 odroid systemd[1]: Started ProImage ICU.
Feb 26 09:39:19 odroid systemd[1]: proimage_daemon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Feb 26 09:39:19 odroid systemd[1]: proimage_daemon.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 26 09:39:19 odroid systemd[1]: proimage_daemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 26 09:39:19 odroid systemd[1]: proimage_daemon.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 26 09:39:19 odroid systemd[1]: Stopped ProImage ICU.
```

I've looked at a dozen posts about this problem. They all say status=200/CHDIR indicates a problem with the working directory.

In my case, the working directory definitely exists and it is owned by root. I've set the permissions to 777 recursively on this directory. I've tried lots of different things with the service file, all to no avail.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to what may be my problem?

Comment: what's your goal with setting RootDirectory? It's akin to a chroot, and it means that systemd is trying to change to /proimage/proimage...

Comment: @JeffSchaller I inherited this service file, so I was trying to get it to run. After deleting the RootDirectory line, the service started! Thanks for you comment.

Comment: So, you're running random `chmod -R 777`s, and running a nodejs service as root? Sounds like a security disaster waiting to happen...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per the [systemd exec documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#), setting `RootDirectory` is akin to a chroot. In combination with setting `WorkingDirectory`, it means that systemd is chrooting your app to `/proimage` and then attempting *within that directory* to `cd /proimage`, which would translate to `/proimage/proimage`.

If you don't need to chroot the process, eliminate the `RootDirectory` directive. If you intend to chroot the process, eliminate the `WorkingDirectory` directive.

Comment: ... If you're running a nodejs application **as root** then chrooting is *not* an unnecessary precaution.

Comment: I should add that there's a third option where /proimage/proimage exists; then you could use both directives.

Comment: @JeffSchaller But then you need a /bin/node inside the /proimage root and also all needed libraries and support files.